# Google Distance Matrix need to return the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have using google distance matrix api to getting the shortest distance of two geo points from the following way:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<script>

    var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(9.6667, 80.0000);
    var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(9.6689, 80.0059);



    function calculateDistances() {


        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
            {
                origins: [origin1],
                destinations: [destinationA],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, callback);

    }

    function callback(response, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            alert('Error was: ' + status);
        } else {
            var origins = response.originAddresses;


            for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                    alert(results[j].distance.text);
                }
            }
        }
    }


</script>
```

On this code I have get the shortest distance successfully. But I need to return the value when calling the method **calculateDistances()** instead of alert the value. How can i do in callback methods!.

Comment: Callback mean to be execute not for return values

Comment: how can i change this method to return method

Comment: Why do you thing you need to "return" the data? The DirectionsMatrix is asynchronous, you can't return anything from its callback function, you have to use the data in the callback function when it is available.  You haven't told use what you are trying to do with the returned data.

Comment: I need to return the data and store them in an array

Comment: I added an updated answer based on the comments here, just in case you still need one. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distance Matrix service is *asynchronous*, for that reason, you need to pass a `callback` method to execute upon completion of the request, to process the results. But you could consider to convert async API to *promises*.

The following example demonstrates how to convert Distance Matrix service API to promises using jQuery:

```js
var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(9.6667, 80.0000);
var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(9.6689, 80.0059);



function calculateDistances(origins,destinations) {
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            var d = $.Deferred();
            service.getDistanceMatrix(
                {
                    origins: origins,
                    destinations: destinations,
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                    avoidHighways: false,
                    avoidTolls: false
                }, 
                function(response, status){
                  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                     d.reject(status);
                  } else {
                     d.resolve(response);
                  }
                });
            return d.promise();
}

        


        calculateDistances([origin1],[destinationA])
           .done(function(response){

                var origins = response.originAddresses;

                for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                    var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                    for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                        //console.log(results[j].distance.text);
                        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += results[j].distance.text;
                    }
                }

           })
           .fail(function(status){
              document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'An error occured. Status: ' + status;
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true"></script>
<div id='result'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make an array as a global variable with the number of elements as well a global variable. Then, in the callback I would increment the number of elements and set the current array element as the distance.

Hope this answers your question. Best of luck!